# Camera focus of opencv4android

Tags: android, opencv

I want to blur the image, so I need to change the focus mode of OpenCV. I created a new class to inherit javacameraview and set the focus mode in the class. Now just change the mopencvcameraview parameter to crash. I can't find the reason. Please take a look, thank you. Another question is how to change camera parameters in javacamera2view?

**MyJavaCameraView**

```
public class MyJavaCameraView extends JavaCameraView {

    public MyJavaCameraView(Context context, int cameraId) {
        super(context, cameraId);
    }

    public MyJavaCameraView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
I want to blur the image, so I need to change the focus mode of OpenCV. I created a new class to inherit javacameraview and set the focus mode in the class. Now just change the mopencvcameraview parameter to crash. I can't find the reason. Please take a look, thank you. Another question is how to change camera parameters in javacamera2view?

    public void setFocusMode() {
        Camera camera = mCamera;
        Camera.Parameters mParameters = camera.getParameters();
        if (camera != null) {
            List<String> supportedFocusModes = mParameters.getSupportedFocusModes();
            if (supportedFocusModes != null && supportedFocusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_INFINITY)) {
                mParameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_INFINITY);
                camera.setParameters(mParameters);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

**ImageManipulationsActivity**

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        setContentView(R.layout.image_manipulations_surface_view);

        mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.image_manipulations_activity_surface_view);
        //Change it to the following crash
        //mOpenCvCameraView = (MyJavaCameraView) findViewById(R.id.image_manipulations_activity_surface_view);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(CameraBridgeViewBase.VISIBLE);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may find it is easier to take the image as normal with the camera and then do the blurring afterwards using openCV.

This will also void you having to test and adapt for different camera capabilities on different devices.

There is some good OpenCV documentation on image blurring here: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html

With most OpenCV documentation I find it is us usually good to understand the approach in the Python examples and then apply to Android, referring to the Android Python class documentation.

Comment: Maybe I didn't make it clear. My only blur is in the state of off focus. Off focus will make the color dots in the image bigger, so it is better to do recognition processing. thank you

Comment: @pamao - I think you can still blur after you have taken the image, and then feed into your recognition code? It will avoid you having to adapt to different camera autofocus HW and software.Its interesting, also, that you find that gives better recognition - have you had a chance to benchmark it against some other approaches - it  might be interesting to share the results if you see a significant improvement, if you are able to?